# Web crawler API

Tags: python, android, ios, api, web-scraping

this is my 1st post here and thank you for reading. I'm a newbie programmer and struggle to build an API between my mobile app and my web crawler (takes credentials to start crawling and return value, python and selenium based).

Currently the thought is: My app enter credentials and feed to crawler, then crawler return result to my app. But what is the method to send the credential to crawler and receive result from crawler to my app is annoying me since i just self study programming.

Really need your ideas and advise. Thank you guys!

Comment: The most simple way to do that is using HTTP Basic Authentication, later you can dive into more advanced topics like OAuth2.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you! Sorry for my bad english, credentials will save on device and it will send to crawler when i open the app, but what needs to be change on my crawler since i code the credential manually in the script now.